# php mysql query returns nothing, phpmyadmin with same query returns result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a file or copy a row into a new table, depending on a $_GET.
The $_GET works fine, and I'm not including all the code, I know it isn't relevant.
The table copy works, but the select statement that gets called when the $_GET is a different value returns nothing, except when I copy the query directly into phpmyadmin.

Base code:

```
$pID = $_GET['pID'];

$con = mysqli_connect("...","...","...","...");
```

The following works:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `photos` (`id`, `photo1`, `photo2`, `demographic_id`)
SELECT `id`, `photo1`, `photo2`, `demographic_id`
FROM `photos_queue`
WHERE `photos_queue`.`demographic_id` = '.$pID;

mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

This does not:

```
$query = 'SELECT `photo1` FROM `photos_queue` WHERE `demographic_id` = '.$pID;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
print($result);
unlink($result);
```

I've printed $query and the value of it is valid; I can copy it directly into phpmyadmin and it will work fine.

Comment: have you echoed out mysqli_error() to see if it is erroring out?

Comment: also, what is the value of `$pID`?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to call `mysqli_fetch_XXX()` to get the row from the query.

Comment: user2722375: A good idiom that is seen a lot when creating these connections is `$con = mysqli_connect("...","...","...","...") or die(mysqli_error());`. Obviously, the call to `die()` kills the script, so I usually use it for debugging... but I think it'd help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` doesn't return the table data, it just returns a resource that can be used to fetch it. You need to do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$filename = $row['photo1'];
print($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

Comment: Aha, that's it!  I looked at another file that was giving me data just fine, but didn't notice I had skipped the mysqli_fetch_assoc/mysqli_fetch_row part.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't delete the file.  The value of photo1 is "foldername/filename.jpg".  I tried prepending "http://mysite.com/" so the value of $filename would be "http://mysite.com/foldername/filename.jpg" but it still doesn't delete.

Comment: That's a totally unrelated problem. I don't know why you would prepend the domain name, filenames are not URLs. If the file is outside the document root, you need to prepend that path. Find the script that creates the file, and see where it puts them.

Comment: "foldername/filename.jpg" is the value I use as the src of an <img> and it works fine.  It's inside of a folder called "foldername" which is in the root folder.

Comment: Maybe prepend `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`? I came here to help you with SQL, I can't really guess the layout of your webserver.

Comment: Are you sure the error is because the pathname is wrong, and not a permissions issue?

Comment: Alright I'll gnaw away at the php part; thanks for the SQL solution, it worked.

Comment: The checkbox next to the answer?  If so, done.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

This should be placed after,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```